# Gtk themes fixing error "Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'."

Tags: gtk3

I've been doing researches to try to find how to fix the error:

```
(launcher:7412): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gnome-applications.css:23:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
```

on Gtk 3+ themes.

It seems to be that this error came when updating to Gtk 3.4.  The best answer that i found was "must add px at the end of the line" they were talking about the css files that
has this kind of content..

```
}

.check:insensitive,
.check row:selected:insensitive,
.check row:selected:focused:insensitive {
    background-image: url("assets/checkbox-unchecked-insensitive-dark.svg");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the gnome-applications.css to some pastebin?

Comment: @lxg Of course, [here](http://pastebin.com/FcS3NAGg) is the link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rewritten due to new information:**

In line 23, the `border-radius` rule needs a measurement unit. Change it to `border-radius: 5px;`. Similar with all the `text-border`, `border-width` etc. rules: they all need a unit. (In this case `px`, because that was the implicit default before.)

Note that after editing, you may have to log out of your Desktop Environment and log in again in order for the CSS to be reloaded.

Comment: we found it at the same time :), I just want to add that is not necessary to Log Out or even change of desktop theme. Just saving the file and relaunching the applications works!

Answer (score 1):

I used these find and replace regexes in Sublime Text 3 to find and fix the 'no px' problems.  I sincerely think I did it correctly.  It seems to work fine.  But I were you, I'd make backup files before running any sort of regexp system like this.  If I'd thought ahead, I've had used 'sed -e -i.Backup', but the regexes aren't exactly the same.

FIND:
-(width|length|height|radius|border|spacing|padding): ([1-9][0-9]*);

REPLACE:
-\1: \2px;

Note that a simple 'whatever-length: 0;' is NOT altered. As zero is the same in all units.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in kali linux as below

```
xfdesktop:----): Gtk-WARNING **:
Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2826:15: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
```

I binged googled around for like 6 hours thats why am sharing the solution.
re-installed my xfce using

```
sudo apt install kali-desktop-xfce
```

still failed until these two youtube videos on

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZrag5LD2VE - Haggai Odanga

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSySW9r5CIg - 5 Minute Guide

then followed his steps as follows:-
FROM : Odagas video:-
install gedit

```
sudo apt install gedit
```

then navigate to the default Home/Your_pc_name  or simply while not in root type "cd"  then immideately press Enter
then edit the shell code with:-

```
sudo nano ~/ bashrc
```

move the cusrsor to the bottom then look for this lines or related ones

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
#this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and/etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if shopt -oq posix; then
if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
   ./usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    ./etc/bash_completion
     fi
fi
```

now paste this below the fi line:-

```
export EDITOR-$(type -p gedit)
export VISUAL-$(type -p gedit)
```

then ctrl O to save press Enter then ctrl X to exit

NOW FROM 5 MINUTE VIDEO:-
Go to root directory:

```
sudo -i
```

while in root type:-

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

press Enter | then no matter the result proceed to the intruction below:-

```
redit /etc/environment
```

Edit it at the bottom of last # intruction and  include:-

```
redit /etc/environment
```

my code after including it is below:-

```
# START KALI-DEFAULTS CONFIG
# Everything from here and until STOP KALI-DEFAULTS CONFIG
# was installed by the kali-defaults package, and it will
# be removed if ever the kali-defaults package is removed.
# If you want to disable a line, please do NOT remove it,
# as it would be added back when kali-defaults is upgraded.
# Instead, comment the line out, and your change will be
# preserved across upgrades.
export DISPLAY=:0
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local>
COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_INSTALL_PROMPT=1
POWERSHELL_UPDATECHECK=Off
POWERSHELL_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
# STOP KALI-DEFAULTS CONFIG
```